# SpaCy string store

Tags: nlp, spacy

I am trying to get the hash values for some English words from the string store of SpaCy.

```py
nlp = English()
doc1 = nlp('this is doc1')
id = doc1.vocab.strings['Saurabh']
print(id)
# output, it has given hash code

id1 = doc1.vocab.strings['समाचार'] 
# This is a hindi word so i do not expect it to be a part of English,
# so it shoud throw an error.
print(id1)
# output, it given hash code
```

Why this is not giving an error in (at least) the 2nd line?

Answer (score 2):

Spacy uses a hash function that assigns an integer to any Unicode string, it is not an index in vocabulary it just a random integer that is used internally for better efficiency. It is a hash function, so it means conflicts are indeed possible, but very unlikely and too rare to have a negative influence on the accuracy of the library, so the efficiency gains outweigh it.